# lfs batch response mismatch with endpoint

Tags: git-lfs

I cloned git project from "https" git server, but when pushing lfs commit to the server, the link in batch response is started with "http", it doesn't match with endpoint of git-lfs env, so the push failed.

After searching on internet, I fount the batch response url was from git server, how to modify that on git server?

Comment: PUT url is incorrect in the issue I met, instead of incorrect POST url mention in LFS document (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/lfs/#getsockopt-connection-refused).

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed with updating HTTPS configuration in gerrit config.

Changes:

1. change gerrit.canonicalWebUrl to “https://{gerrit url}/"
2. change "httpd.listenUrl" to "proxy-https://*:8081/"